# Elasticsearch shard allocation for small indices

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

I have an elasticsearch setup with 192 active indices ranging from a few hundred mb to possibly 5gb each. I read that for a logstash use case with 1gb indices you should only use 1 shard. The difference with my setup is that I will be having more users (estimate of up to 100) expecting a quick response time. I intend to have 1 replica for reliability.

Will having 1 shard per index still be appropriate for my use case?

Comment: If the main thing you are worried about is search performance you can easily add or remove replicas, don't need to worry about shard sizing for search performance on small indices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word: yes.

The need to create multiple primary shards derives from the need to isolate documents, extreme counts (e.g., when you're in the billions of documents volume), or to improve write throughput (write documents across more places, thereby reducing individual burden).

In practice, you want to shard based on your use case, unless you're one of those first two scenarios (isolation or extreme counts).

- Are you read heavy?
- Are you write heavy? (Less common, but it does happen)

If you're read heavy, as most use cases are, then having fewer shards will help you by limiting the request size (fewer places to look). Given that your shard sizes are also relatively small (I'd consider anything under 5 GB to be relatively small), you can easily get away with having a single *primary* shard and it should benefit your search performance by doing so.

Indexes that share the same mappings, but are also tiny ("few hundred MBs"), should likely be combined *if you search across them*. If they're independent, then it really makes no difference and the isolation sounds like good practice at the expense of slightly bloating your cluster state (with each index).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I may look at combining some of the smaller ones. We were planning to close them off on rolling months, but it may be better to close them in large batches as one index.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this blog: https://qbox.io/blog/optimizing-elasticsearch-how-many-shards-per-index. He has a lot of good pointers to sharding and shard sizing.

However, the question you really should be asking yourself is: How easy is it to change? When it comes to sizing and scalability, the answer often is "it depends" - and the real question is: How quickly can you reconfigure?

This could e.g. mean that you design you application in a way, that allows quick re-spooling of data into a new index, that you use aliases so that you can in fact change these things, where your data lies (not just in Elastic, I hope) etc.

By building a system - from the start - so that you can quickly rebuild indicies enables you to experiment with sizes - and more importantly - change them as your need changes.

Comment: Yeah this is the article that left me with this question. I'm hoping to build a quick re-index process although it largely depends on the resources I'm given.